# Como passar frases para uma variável e depois mostrar de forma aleatória

Tags: android, react, react-native, atom

Bom, eu comecei ontem a programar em React Native e ainda não entendo muito bem como fazer as coisas.... Preciso de passar uma série de frases para várias variáveis, cada variável uma frase, e depois apresentá-las de forma aleatória.

```
onPlay(){
      // const um = "testeeeeee";
}

// EVENTS
// SPECIFIC METHODS

render() {   
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            Would You Rather
          </Text>
          <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.primary_button,styles.medium_button]} onPress={this.onPlay.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.medium_button_text}>
            test
          </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.primary_button,styles.medium_button]} onPress={this.onPlay.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.medium_button_text}>
            test2
          </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Não tens `state` nem `props`? de onde vêm essas frases?

Comment: as frases eu estava a pensar passa-las a mao para as variaveis diretamente no codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deves ter essas frases nas `props` ou no `state` do componente. Sendo esse o caso, para evitar duplicar código podes fazer assim:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        frases: [
            {title: 'frase 1', conteudo: 'Olá!'},
            {title: 'frase 2', conteudo: 'Olé!'}
    };
}

// para as misturar aleatoriamente
function misturador() {
    const array = this.state.frases.slice();
    let length = array.length;
    while (counter > 0) {
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        length--;
        let temp = array[length];
        array[length] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
render() {   
    const frases = this.misturador().map(frase => (
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{frase.title}</Text>
          <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.primary_button,styles.medium_button]} onPress={this.onPlay.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.medium_button_text}>{frase.conteudo}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    ));
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {frases}
      </View>
    );
}
```

Outra maneira, talvez ainda melhor é ter um componente para esse texto e gerir dentro do componente como o titulo é tratado. Depois usas da mesma maneira, com um `.map()` da array de frases para o componente.

Comment: mas assim vao aparecer todas as frases que estao dentro de 
 frases: [
            {title: 'frase 1', conteudo: 'Olá!'},
            {title: 'frase 2', conteudo: 'Olé!'}
    };
certo?

Comment: @AlexandreSeabra exato. Se nem todas tiverem `title` tens de juntar um `if/else` algures, ou fazeres como sugeri no fim: um componente que gere isso à parte para essa logica não estar dentro do `render` deste componente.

Comment: ok, vou tentar, obrigado

Comment: @AlexandreSeabra juntei mais um método, não tinha reparado que querias as frases aleatoriamente.